# How To render more views in one view or controller

Tags: php, view, cakephp-2.0

How can I render 2 views in a single view in cake PHP,

I tried like below ,

In view/test/index.ctp ,

> echo $this->render('/page1/index');
>
> echo $this->render('/page2/index');

my view/page1/index.ctp,

> echo "content from page1";

my view/page2/index.ctp,

> echo "content from page2";

I am expecting output as ,

> my content from page1 my content from page2

but I am getting as my content from page1 1

Please suggest me how can I acheive this.

Comment: Why won't you use elements?

Comment: Use elements. You can know more about elements in this link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements

Comment: @Dachi N  ,Saranya Sadhasivam, thanks for the quick reply, I will check with elements what u suggested

Comment: You cannot render multiple views in CakePHP, but Yes you can render n number of elements in one view.

Comment: These comments should be answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(just adding an answer so this question shows as answered, even though it's effectively been answered in the comments)*

As others have mentioned in the comments, you can only render one view from your controller. You'll want to use [elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements). Elements are re-usable view snippets.

If you had a view file called `my_view.ctp`, you could add the following code to it, to include two elements, called 'hello_world' and 'name_details':

```
$this->element('hello_world'); // <= element with no parameters

// example passing parameters to the element
$this->element('name_details', array('first' => 'John', 'last' => 'smith'));
```

You're element files will go in `app/views/elements` and will be called `hello_world.ctp`, and `name_details.ctp`. The parameters you passed in will be available as variables, so `name_details.ctp` might look like this:

```
First Name: <?php echo $first; ?>
<br />
Last Name: <?php echo $last; ?>
```

Also note that view variables set in your controller will automatically be available in elements.